# AOP based transaction management for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, unity-container, aop

Is there a Unity Container library for the doing AOP based transaction management for EntityFramework?

For example, using Spring.NET and Nhibernate if I want to mark a particular service method as transactional I would do something like this:

```
[Transaction]
public void DoSomething()
{
    Product p = new Product("Cucumber");
    productDao.save(p);
}
```

regards,
Jordan.

Comment: Seems to me that you're better of by changing your design, for instance by using [the command/handler pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and implement a [decorator that adds transaction behavior](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91#TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator).

Comment: Sorry Steven, I've only had a quick look but that looks like an inferior approach to me.

Comment: Inferior? Why did you find inferior? I think this is more powerful than code weaving aop framework like postsharp.

Comment: Sorry the use of the word "inferior" is inflammatory and I see that you have linked to your own blog, so I apologise. Also I do accept that the use of the Command pattern can be very powerful. But I like AOP based transaction management and see no need to implement all services as commands. Also does this approach assume that all code that needs to be made transactional only takes 1 parameter? Finally, AOP solutions will often let you set properties of the transaction eg isolation level. (also this is not relevant to the point but it doesn't have to be code weaving...it can be proxy based)

Comment: "does this approach assume that all code that needs to be made transactional only takes 1 parameter?" Yep. That one parameter is the command, which is a [parameter object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object).

Comment: Ok - well I usually use that approach for services anyway, but sometimes you might have a service with no parameters that needs to be transactional. Overall I still don't think this is "more powerful" as you suggest. Infact it introduces limitations. If I chose to use the command pattern I would probably then use AOP if I wanted to make the commands transactional. In the .NET and Java dev I have done I have found this to be one of the most useful applications of AOP.

Comment: Your suggestion actually reinforces why AOP is such a good fit for this problem. It is a cross cutting concern. Transactions should not be tightly coupled to commands, or any other type of code. You should be able to apply them anywhere.

Comment: @gusgorman You have not looked deeply enough into understanding the detailed knowledge that can be found in the linked articles. Between them those two articles explain **the concept of employing interfaces and decorators to implement AOP** - command handlers are an example - don't for one minute believe that is their limit. The main benefit of designing aspects with *interfaces*, *implementations* and *decorators* is that each part can be individually unit tested. If this feels like too much work for you then look at [postsharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), good luck unit testing that stuff!

Comment: @quijck I already understand the concept of interfaces and decorators. I have understood it for years. I don't need to use the technique suggested above, and I don't need to explicitly use postsharp either, because I am using a dependency injection container (in this case Unity) that allows me to implement interceptors. These interceptors are implemented as proxies (ie decorators!) so give me exactly the same functionality. I have used this technique on multiple enterprise level projects over years and years - and btw have successfully implemented extensive unit testing on those projects.

Comment: @gusgorman inteceptors was not mentioned in your question so I had missed that connection. My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @qujck Ah ok that makes sense. Apology accepted :) Interceptors is an addon for the unity container.